# Propagating events from d3.js to angular without resorting to scope.apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-scope, angularjs-events

I am using the d3.js library inside an angular 1.x controller.
My d3.js library creates a click event on a div and when the div is clicked, it updates something on the angular controller's scope.

The problem is, when I change the scope (`$scope.test = "a test"`), the modification is not reported into the template.

However, if, inside that d3.js click event, I do a $scope.$apply (as suggested by this related topic: [Angular + D3 - Get scope values to show in template from click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260452/angular-d3-get-scope-values-to-show-in-template-from-click-event)), the dom is updated and everything works fine.

Since the use of scope is discouraged, is there another solution that will make the changes appear in my template?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.1/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div  ng-app="app" >
    <div id="main" ng-controller="main">    
      test is {{test}}
      <div id="graph">
        hello  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('main', function($scope){

    $scope.force_refresh = function(){}

    d3.selectAll("#graph").on("click", function() {
      $scope.test = "a test";
      //////////I would like to avoid this/////////////
      $scope.$apply();             ////////////////////
      //////////I would like to avoid this/////////////
    });
  });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should you avoid `$scope`? this is where all the angular magic happens...

Comment: because the use of $scope is discouraged because it tends to create unmanageable code ("scope soup").
Another reason is that if I want to migrate my code to Angular2, then I don't have a scope at all so how would I refresh there?

Comment: You can use the controllerAs syntax

Comment: Yes of course but what is the equivalent of $scope.$apply (that I need in my case) in the controllerAs syntax? That would solve my problem.

Comment: There is no equivalent. You're going to need to apply anyway. In angular2 it's Lifecycle::tick()